# Understanding output of model.get_weights() in Keras

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

To get a feeling of how neural nets work, I decided to train a super simple 2-1 net to add up its two inputs. Here's my code.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math

x_train = np.random.rand(10000,2)
y_train = x_train[:,0]+x_train[:,1]

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mean_square_error,
    metrics=[]
)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)



for i in model.get_weights():
    print(i, '\n')
```

The output of the previous code is the following.

```
[[ 0.8512728   1.555682  ]
 [-0.04689309  1.6778996 ]]

[-0.23842156 -0.06958904]

[[0.09876956] [0.583725  ]]

[0.08260487]
```

The model behaves well, with an average mean square error of around *0.0001*. However...

- I don't understand why there are **two** weight matrices. Why isn't there only one, namely the weights from the first (input) to the second (output) layer?
- How could I go about performing the same calculations as my model `model` given those weights and biases? Like, I think I knew the basic algebraic theory of neural nets but now that this first *2×2* weight matrix shows up, I'm not really sure of how it works. In particular, given an input ***x***, and considering the weights and biases from the aforequoted output as *W0, b0, W1, b1* respectively, I've tried to compute ***y**=W1(W1****x*** *+b0) +b1* but this really isn't near the output of the net, and ***y*** also strongly disagrees with *(1, 1)**x*** (the ideal output). I'm therefore in the utter blue as to what's happening behind the scenes.

Please, can someone tell me what I'm missing here? What do *W0, b0, W1* and *b1* represent?

Comment: You have an outdated view of neural networks, here each layer has weights, that is why there are two weight matrices (one per layer).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think the input "layer" is *not* considered a layer in Keras. My goal being to build a net with 2 input nodes and 1 output node, I think I should have ommited the line `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2),`, where I was unsuspectingly creating a layer which I thought was the input but instead is backbone layer right after the input (hence the square matrix *W0*). Is this what you mean by "outdated"? I guess that in this new architecture the weight matrices "belong" to the Layer object to which they point? This architecture feels most natural to me as it allows for easy scaling.